# Human who is a contract worker for aliens?

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about interstellar assassin?

Okay, so I read this book around 2012? It's a regular guy on earth, who knows he has a weird job but not what it is. After each mission he forgets it and thinks he is a normal guy. The only thing he knows is that he leaves beers in his fridge to remember people by. So he gets a new mission to go to a second earth and I think kill someone? Anyway long story short he finds out that his alien employers want the person taken out because they are trying to advance "too quickly" so he doesn't kill the person and he teams up with a girl to do it? He has 2 weeks and the 2 weeks end too fast and he forgets everything too soon. He has a catch phrase he always starts saying as he forgets to help himself feel grounded, and she repeats it to him to gain his trust and explain to him what's going on. At the end of the book he goes after the aliens who made him like this. Any ideas? I don't remember the title, the author or even what it looked like.

Comment: Almost certainly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195587/story-about-an-assassin-who-travels-to-a-parallel-earth-to-carry-out-an-assassin. The bottles of beer thing is memorable and distinctive.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I've spent weeks trying to figure this out!!!

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate. That does not mean that it is a bad question. We just have had it asked before. You will still get points for upvotes.

Comment: @BlackWidow1321 - [You're most welcome](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)